# What is the importance of the bigger Lie algebra for the tensor hierarchy?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

Much of the work on the embedding tensor and on tensor hierarchies seems to use the lager Lie algebra g superfluously. Where does it matter? or is it just an `appendix' left over from the physical exam[ples?